# Cakephp 3 : How to receive get request data?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have written ajax to send search key, I have tried below code

```
$.ajax({
              method:'GET',
              url:'<?php echo Router::url(['action' => 'product_search']); ?>',
              data:{search:search},
              success: function(data)
              {
                $('.fetch-data').html(data);
              }
});
```

Then I have received it in product controller like

```
if ($this->request->is(['get'])) {
             $search   = $this->request->data('search');       
}
```

Here `$search` is null. If I use `POST` in here then it's working fine. How can I receive this data by get method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Used below code in product controller

```
if ($this->request->is(['get'])) {
    $search = $this->request->query('search');       
}
```

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Request & Response Objects > Query String Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)**

Comment: The function can also be called without the array notation, like `$this->request->is('get')`, or using the magic function notation, like `$this->request->isGet()`