# Parameters in CakePHP3 URL

Tags: url, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP3, I have a search form with `GET` method. Trying to get the URL parameter seems not to work. I doing as follow :

```
if(isset($this->request->params['text'])){

        // the code ...
    }
```

The search form's action has a defined route :

```
$routes->connect('/search', [
  'controller' => 'Top',
  'action' => 'index'
],
[
  '_name' => 'search'
]);
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried this? var_dump($this) or var_dump($this->request->params['text'])

Comment: **[Request & Response Objects > Query String Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)**

Comment: `var_dump($this->request->params['text'])` returns `NULL`. Though, my URL displays `localhost/app/search?text=toto`.

Comment: Thanks @ndm. Fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp 3 : How to receive get request data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142015/cakephp-3-how-to-receive-get-request-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this fo fetch querystring($_GET) parameters

```
if(isset($this->request->query['text'])){
        // the code ...
}
```

Comment: It seems like `isset()` cannot be called with a function as a parameter. I can rather do this : 
`$text = $this->request->query['text'];
if(isset($text)){ /*... */ }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$this->request->query('text');
```

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters